# Office 365 add-ins ribbon bar buttons are disabled

Tags: vsto, office365, outlook-2016, addin-express

To isolate issue I created an empty add-in express project (Regions for Outlook and VSTO) as follows:

- outlook 2013/2016 vsto project
- added adx region for outlook and VSTO
- explorer layout: taskpanedock.right
- explorer item types: checked MailItem
- no inspector selected (just explorer)

click new mail - all installed office 365 add-ins ribbon bar buttons are disabled (ie. evernote, findtime, etc)

tested with outlook 2016 connected to office 365 account

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump bug reports.

Comment: This is a huge issue for anyone creating a traditional com add-in for outlook. The question is does anyone know a way in a com add-in to avoid this issue.

Comment: No luck from Add-In Express support?